# Debounce FCM notifications in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Scenario**

I'm receiving data notifications from FCM periodically. The notifications trigger a sync operation

**Problem**

Sometimes the notifications come in bursts, thus triggering multiple sync operations at the same time

**Solution**

A debounce on FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       if(remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("one_notification_key")){
            // DEBOUNCE -> execute the code only once after some cooling period
       }
    }
}
```

**Question: How can I implement the debounce in this context?**

*Note that I do not want to execute the first and ignore the rest for a period of time. I'd rather want to execute the last from a burst of notifications spanned over a period

Answer (score 0):

Example how to ignore previous messages if another  one arrives less than 1 second later.

```
        private RemoteMessage lastMessage;

        Handler handler =  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executeOperation(lastMessage);
            }
        };



        //When one message arrives
        lastMessage = remoteMessage;
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when using Handler with FirebaseMessagingService's thread.  "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"